# Django EncryptedCharField Error When Editing Value

Tags: django, encryption, pycrypto, django-extensions

Here's one for my Django comrades.

I am trying to build an application in Django 1.6.5 and MySQL where some database fields are encrypted in order to respect the privacy of users.  I have successfully installed `django-extensions` and successfully used the `EncryptedCharField` to do a simple save and data retrieval.

However, I am running into a problem when using `EncryptedCharField` for floats.  Now, simple typecasting has been useful--this problem doesn't seem to be that problem.  I'm trying to start with an encrypted field that is a value, change the value by adding/subtracting some number, then save the back to the database.  I've managed to reduce and reproduce the error like this:

```
>>> user_id = 1
>>> account = AccountCash.objects.get( id = 1 )
>>> account.id
1L
>>> account.portfolio_id
1L
>>> account.account_name
u'My Cash'
>>> account.current_value
u'200'
>>> account.current_value = account.current_value - 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Here, `account_name` and `current_value` are both `EncryptedCharField`s.  We see that `current_value` is a unicode, so typecasting to a `float` should (I thought) resolve the issue, as it has for me in other places.

However, doing so leads to another problem in

```
>>> account.current_value = float(account.current_value) - 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jasonnett/anaconda/envs/bb_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 35, in __set__
    obj.__dict__[self.field.name] = self.field.to_python(value)
  File "/Users/jasonnett/anaconda/envs/bb_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/db/fields/encrypted.py", line 69, in to_python
    elif value and (value.startswith(self.prefix)):
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I haven't been able to figure out what is different about assigning a float value to the encrypted field here vs. where I originally set the value like this:

```
        # Make the new account, passing in the portfolio it belongs to
        new_account = AccountCash(
            portfolio                   = portfolio,
            account_name                = newCashAccountForm.cleaned_data['account_name'],
            starting_balance            = newCashAccountForm.cleaned_data['starting_balance'],
            current_value               = newCashAccountForm.cleaned_data['starting_balance'],
        )
        new_account.save()
```

Comment: I found the problem: I need to typecast back to a unicode like this:

    `account.current_value = unicode( float(account.current_value) - 10 )`

Comment: Either supply a full answer or delete the question if it is of no use to other readers.

Comment: Either provide something useful to say or stop trolling my post.

Comment: I'm not trolling your post, please read the guidelines on how to use SO. Comments are for comments like such as these. They should not be used for answers; in that sense you are trolling your own post.